# Is it possible to add inline bitmap object to the body of an email sent via JavaMail?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jakarta-mail

I'd like to add an inline bitmap (generated within the code) to an email to be sent via JavaMail in Android. Below is my code currently:

```
try {
            // Compose the message
            // javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage class is
            // mostly used for abstraction.
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            // header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("service@someone.com"));

            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject("Workside Verification Service");
            message.setText(
                    "Thank you for registering. Please click on the following link to activate your account:\n\n"
                            + urlWithToken
                            + "\n\nRegards,\nThe Workside Team");

            // Add the generated QR code bitmap here
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
            MimeBodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            // imageFile is the file containing the image

            // TODO - pass bitmap to imageFile below
            File file = new File(null);
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

            mBitmapQR.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, os);


            imgPart.attachFile(imageFile);
            multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(message); // send Message

            System.out.println("Email Sent");

        } catch (MessagingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

I was thinking of converting the bitmap to a File object and then adding it to the body of the message, but I was thinking that there could be a more straightfirward and efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

The Jakarta Mail FAQ is your best resource.  See [How do I send HTML mail that includes images?](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ#sendmpr).  That describes 3 choices:

1. Link image to web site, which I doubt works for you.
2. Inline the image `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,base64-encoded-data-here" />`
3. Construct a multipart/related message as you are doing.

Comment: Hi I figured out my issue and posted it in my answer, after I had a better understanding of `Multipart`. The image is still added as an attachment, so if need be changed, I'll use the inline code you have provided!

Answer (score 0):

The issue, as seen from the code, was that I was adding the text to the multipart, then the image (effectively overriding the text), and then I was assigning the multipart to the message. The solution was to add the text, using `addBodyPart(text)`, and then use `addBodyPart(image)`. After that, I could use `setContent(multipart)` to properly assign the text and image to the email.

```
    // Add the generated QR code bitmap here
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
    MimeBodyPart imgPart = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Set the cache path and generate the new file image
    String mFilePath = mContext.getCacheDir().toString();
    File file = new File(mFilePath, FILE_NAME);
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));

    // TITLE
    message.setSubject("Workside Verification Service");
    // TEXT
    MimeBodyPart txtPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    txtPart.setContent("Welcome to Workside! \n\nPlease proceed by scanning the QR code provided using the Workside application available in the Google Play store.\n\n\n"
                                + "Regards,\n\nThe Workside Team", "text/plain");
    // ADD TEXT
    multipart.addBodyPart(txtPart);
    // Generate image using the QR Bitmap, and attach it
    mBitmapQR.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
    imgPart.attachFile(mFilePath + FILE_NAME);
    // ADD IMAGE
    multipart.addBodyPart(imgPart);
    message.setContent(multipart);
```